# Laravel error Trying to get property 'date' of non-object only when deployed

Tags: laravel, hosting

I have a `Package Model` which belongs to `Shipment Model`. I have set the relationship like this

```
class Package extends Model
{
  public function shipment(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Shipment::class,'shipment_id','id');
    }
}
```

Everything is working properly in `localhost` but when I deploy it to `heroku` it's showing me error

```
Trying to get property 'date' of non-object

    ErrorException
    in /app/app/Http/Resources/Package.php (line 19)
         'shipment_date'=> $this->shipment->date
```

Comment: `$this->shipment` is null value. Thats why it shows the error

Comment: `$this->shipment` is not null i checked it

Comment: The thing it is working in local computer but not when deployed

Comment: You can try `optional($this->shipment)->date`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
$this->shipment['date']
```